# Angular2 - get content of external website

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the HTML of an external website and what I want is, since the external website loads the video async and the video loads after some time in the site, to wait until the external website finishes loading and rendering all HTML (including the video).

Right now, when I get the HTML, the video container is empty since the response came before video was rendered.

Is there any way I can do this with Angular 2?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @ACOMIT001, I have not tried nothing special, I just do http.get request to specific webpage, and it returns me the html code, but, since the video is loaded after some time, the video <div> is empty on the response.

Comment: how are you going to render the html? in an iframe?

Comment: @shusson , i would render whatever is best practice, which one solves the problem in best way, i can do it like that.